# does using optimizer_mode=first_rows_n for application that using Oracle database is a best practice?

Tags: oracle, performance, database-design, java, tuning

So I'm working in application that involving display of data in table/grid. And the grid will invoke paging query to oracle. So does by tuning my application to get the best query cost with `optimizer_mode=first_rows_10` is always good and consider best practice with this kind paging search with html table or any table based approach application.

Comment: What do your benchmarks say?

Comment: benchmark return better result compare to when first_rows_n not set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not ready to make this a system-wide setting, you could try it in an isolated fashion by using a query hint:

```
SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS(10) */
       first_column,
       second_column
  FROM my_table_or_view
```

This is less risky, since you don't need to consider the effects on the entire system.

Comment: Good advice . Thx